# Deserialise JSON array to list of object

Tags: vb.net, json, deserialization, javascriptserializer

I'm trying to deserialise some JSON in .NET, using JavascriptSerializer. An example of the JSON I'm working with is as follows:

```
[{
"dep_date": "2012-07-12", 
"tax": 141.53, 
"currency": "GBP", 
"vcr": "LX", 
"dst_apt": "PRG", 
"flight_in": [
    [
        {
            "depApt": "PRG", 
            "dstApt": "FRA", 
            "depTime": "2012-07-15 19:05:00", 
            "vcr": "LH", 
            "carrier": "LH", 
            "arrTime": "2012-07-15 20:15:00", 
            "ocr": "LH", 
            "flightNo": "1401"
        }, 
        {
            "depApt": "FRA", 
            "dstApt": "LHR", 
            "depTime": "2012-07-15 21:30:00", 
            "vcr": "LH", 
            "carrier": "LH", 
            "arrTime": "2012-07-15 22:10:00", 
            "ocr": "LH", 
            "flightNo": "922"
        }
    ]
], 
"price": 114.0, 
"dst_city": "PRG", 
"dep_apt": "LCY", 
"flight_out": [
    [
        {
            "depApt": "LCY", 
            "dstApt": "ZRH", 
            "depTime": "2012-07-12 08:25:00", 
            "vcr": "LX", 
            "carrier": "LX", 
            "arrTime": "2012-07-12 11:15:00", 
            "ocr": "LX", 
            "flightNo": "451"
        }, 
        {
            "depApt": "ZRH", 
            "dstApt": "PRG", 
            "depTime": "2012-07-12 12:35:00", 
            "vcr": "LX", 
            "carrier": "LX", 
            "arrTime": "2012-07-12 13:55:00", 
            "ocr": "2L", 
            "flightNo": "1486"
        }
    ]
], 
"ret_date": "2012-07-15", 
}]
```

The actual code/classes I'm using are:

```
<Serializable()> _
    Public Class FareResult

        Public Property dep_date As String
        Public Property tax As String
        Public Property currency As String
        Public Property vcr As String
        Public Property dst_apt As String
        Public Property flight_in As List(Of FlightResult)
        Public Property price As String
        Public Property dst_city As String
        Public Property dep_apt As String
        Public Property flight_out As List(Of FlightResult)
        Public Property ret_date As String

    End Class

    <Serializable()> _
    Public Class FlightResult

        Public Property depApt As String
        Public Property dstApt As String
        Public Property depTime As String
        Public Property vcr As String
        Public Property carrier As String
        Public Property arrTime As String
        Public Property ocr As String
        Public Property flightNo As String

    End Class

Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer
Dim oFareResults As Generic.List(Of FareResult) = jss.Deserialize(Of List(Of FareResult))(sJSON)
```

However, this just gives me a message saying the type FlightResults is not supported for deserialization of an array. I've tried creating a class that inherits a list of FlightResults, I've tried setting it as an array instead of a list, but they all give the same exception.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Changing `flight_in` and `flight_out` to arrays works (note `()` at the end).

```
Public Property flight_in As List(Of FlightResult)()
Public Property flight_out As List(Of FlightResult)()
```

Your JSON has some parsing errors (run it through a [validator](http://jsonlint.com/)). Note the removal of the comma near the end. Here is a fixed copy that works.

```js
[{
"dep_date": "2012-07-12", 
"tax": 141.53, 
"currency": "GBP", 
"vcr": "LX", 
"dst_apt": "PRG", 
"flight_in": [
    [
        {
            "depApt": "PRG", 
            "dstApt": "FRA", 
            "depTime": "2012-07-15 19:05:00", 
            "vcr": "LH", 
            "carrier": "LH", 
            "arrTime": "2012-07-15 20:15:00", 
            "ocr": "LH", 
            "flightNo": "1401"
        }, 
        {
            "depApt": "FRA", 
            "dstApt": "LHR", 
            "depTime": "2012-07-15 21:30:00", 
            "vcr": "LH", 
            "carrier": "LH", 
            "arrTime": "2012-07-15 22:10:00", 
            "ocr": "LH", 
            "flightNo": "922"
        }
    ]
], 
"price": 114.0, 
"dst_city": "PRG", 
"dep_apt": "LCY", 
"flight_out": [
    [
        {
            "depApt": "LCY", 
            "dstApt": "ZRH", 
            "depTime": "2012-07-12 08:25:00", 
            "vcr": "LX", 
            "carrier": "LX", 
            "arrTime": "2012-07-12 11:15:00", 
            "ocr": "LX", 
            "flightNo": "451"
        }, 
        {
            "depApt": "ZRH", 
            "dstApt": "PRG", 
            "depTime": "2012-07-12 12:35:00", 
            "vcr": "LX", 
            "carrier": "LX", 
            "arrTime": "2012-07-12 13:55:00", 
            "ocr": "2L", 
            "flightNo": "1486"
        }
    ]
], 
"ret_date": "2012-07-15"
}]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to do anything. I get about 25 errors in a file called SGEN, that "cannot be opened. It has been renamed, deleted or moved". Not entirely sure why. Changing it to flight_in() As List(Of FlightResult) doesn't work either.

Comment: @user1546281 Your JSON had some parsing errors. I updated the answer with valid JSON. Try it with that. It *does* fix the problem.